django user login gives error always as the admin with this phone number already exist
I have a custom user model with username field phone_number inherited from AbstractBaseUser and PermissionMixin.I have multiple collge and each college has separate custom admin panel.I have created a admin for each college and i have create a login template to login each college admin.
view.py
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(request, username=phone_number, password=password)
            print(f"phone_number: {phone_number}")
            print(f"password: {password}")
            print(f"User: {user}")
            if user is not None:
                auth_login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, "Login successful")
                return redirect('dashboard')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Login failed. Enter valid credentials and try again.")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Form is invalid. Please check the entered data.")
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form})

models.py
class Custom_user(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    phone_number=models.CharField(max_length=13,validators=[phone_validator],unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD='phone_number'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=[]
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = Custom_user_manager()
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return  self.phone_number
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Admin'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Admins'

form.py
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Custom_user
        fields = ['phone_number', 'password']
        
        widgets={
            'password':forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['phone_number'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
            self.fields['password'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})

Whenever i click the login button it gives the error as The admin with phone number already exist

I’ll give my two cents. Hopefully you will find it useful. If you already had data in your database before making the phone_number field unique and making migrations, that error will pop up every now and then.

Im guessing that since you subclass LoginForm from ModelForm, during validation, it may check for uniqueness? Can you change LoginForm to subclass from normal forms.Form and try?
